# Brezis' exercise 8.18: show that $u$ is the solution of some ODE with appropriate boundary conditions

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 1)$. I'm trying to solve a problem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 8.18** Check that the mapping $v \mapsto v(0)$ from $H^1(I)$ into $\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous linear functional on $H^1(I)$. Deduce that there exists a unique $u \in H^1(I)$ such that
> $$
> v(0)=\int_I (u' v'+u v) \quad \forall v \in H^1(I) .
> $$
>
> Show that $u$ is the solution of some differential equation with appropriate boundary conditions. Compute $u$ explicitly.

Below, I prove that

> The function $u$ is the unique classical solution of the ODE
> $$
> (1) \quad
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> -u''+u=f \quad \text { on } I, \\
> u'(0)=\alpha, u'(1)=\beta,
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
>
> where $f \equiv 0, \alpha=-1, \beta=0$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in my below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

If $u$ is a classical solution of (1), we have
$$
-\int_I u'' v + \int_I u v=\int_I f v,
\quad v \in H^1(I).
$$

By integration by parts (I.b.P),
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_I u^{\prime \prime} v &= (u'v)(1)- (u'v)(0) - \int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime} \\
&= \beta v(1)-  \alpha v (0) - \int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime},
\quad v \in H^1(I),
\end{align*}
$$

which implies
$$
(2) \quad
\int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime}+\int_I u v=\int_I f v + \beta v(1)-\alpha v(0),
\quad v \in H^1(I) .
$$

By Lax-Milgram theorem, there is a unique $u \in H^1 (I)$ that satisfies $(2)$. In particular,
$$
(3) \quad
\int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime}=-\int_I (u-f) v,
\quad v \in H^1_0(I),
$$

which implies $u \in H^2 (I)$ with $u'' =u-f$. By I.b.P,
$$
(4) \quad
 \int_I u^{\prime \prime} v = (u'v) (1) - (u'v) (0) - \int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime},
\quad v \in H^1 (I) .
$$

We have $(2, 4)$ and the fact that $-u^{\prime \prime} + u=f$ a.e. on $I$ imply
$$
(\beta - u' (1)) v (1) +(u'(0)- \alpha) v (0) = 0
\quad v \in H^1 (I),
$$
and thus $\beta = u'(1)$ and $\alpha = u' (0)$. Then it follows from (2) that
$$
\int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime}+\int_I u v= v(0),
\quad v \in H^1(I) .
$$

Notice that $f$ being continuous implies $u''$ being continuous. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $v: H^1(I)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $v\to v(0)$ is linear. First for $\forall v \in H^1(I)$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
v(0)&=&\int_I (u' v'+u v)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=&\int_I (u' v'+u v)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=&\int_I u'\mathrm{d}v+\int_I uv\mathrm{d}x\\
&=&u'(1)v(1)-u'(0)v(0)+\int_I(-u''+u)v\mathrm{d}x
\end{eqnarray*}
which implies
$$ -u''+u=0, \text{ in }I, \ u'(0)=-1, u'(1)=0. \tag{*}$$
The equation has the solution
$$ u=c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t} $$
with $c_1=\frac1{e^2-1},c_2=\frac{e^2}{e^2-1}$.

Conversely for $\forall v \in H^1(I)$, one has, from (*) and by IBP
$$ \int_I(-u''+u)v\mathrm{d}x=\int_I(u'v'+uv)\mathrm{d}x-(u'(1)v'(1)-u'(0)v'(0))=\int_I(u'v'+uv)\mathrm{d}x-v(0). $$
Define
$$ a(u,v)=\int_I(u'v'+uv)\mathrm{d}x, u, v \in H^1(I)$$
which is continuous and coercive. Since $v: H^1(I)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $v\to v(0)$ is linear, by Lax-Milgram theorem, there is $u\in H^1(I)$ such that $a(u,v)=v(0)$ or
$$ \int_I (u' v'+u v)\mathrm{d}x=v(0), \forall v \in H^1(I). $$